# Sur + "ville" : est-il correct de parler ainsi?

Tags: grammaire

Lorsque l'on parle d'une ville, peut-on utiliser la préposition *sur* ?

On peut bien sûr dire, « Je vis à Barcelone » mais peut-on dire « [Je vis sur Barcelone](https://bonjourbarcelone.fr/) » ?

C'est une phrase que j'entends souvent mais je ne sais pas si c'est correct grammaticalement parlant.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de problème d'un point de vue grammatical: *sur* est une proposition qui peut indiquer un lieu donc la phrase *Je vis sur Barcelone* est parfaitement correcte.

D'un point de vue idiomatique, j'utiliserai quand même plutôt *J'habite sur Barcelone* ou *Je travaille sur Barcelone*. L'expression *vivre sur* est plutôt utilisée pour un moyen d'existence: *je vis sur les deniers de mon père* et elle sonne mal à mes oreilles pour un lieu élargi. Mais ce n'est que mon opinion ...